# How to perform left join in Hibernate Query Language?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql

This is my HQL query, but it isn't working and is throwing an error.

Hql query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    TABLEA A 
LEFT JOIN 
    A.TABLEB B 
WHERE 
    A.COLUMNNAME = B.COLUMNAME
```

and it causes this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException:
This Query caught Exception. could not resolve property: of TABLEB:TABLEA.
```

How can I solve this problem? Actually I retrieved a value from more than one table. This query doesn't work with [`CreateQuery(strQuery)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Renovate and simplify the myquery.Pls tell any possible answer

Comment: why are you joining with A.TABLEB, it should be only TABLEB.

Comment: I need join two seperate table and match one column,that's why joining these table

Answer (score 14):

In `HQL` you can use `LEFT JOIN` only with linked property in main entity:

Sample

EntityA has an object entityB of type EntityB so you can

```
SELECT A FROM EntityA A LEFT JOIN A.entityB B WHERE ...
```

IF EntityA haven't entityB property but is EntityB have a property entityA, you can't write this:

```
SELECT A FROM EntityA LEFT JOIN EntityB B WHERE B.entityA = A
```

because you have an error. This is an Hibernate issue not resolved yet.