# Hibernate HQL Left Join Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables which I need to be joined but there in **no relation specified in the entity**. Can I write something like

```
select uc.id, uc.name, mpn.name from UCR uc, MpnMapping mpn
```

I'm getting an error called **Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545390/how-to-perform-left-join-in-hibernate-query-language - Try this but This question has no accepted or upvoted answer. I post it before test it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by specifing the join in the `where` clause. It must be something like this:

```
select a, b from A a, B b where a.joinColumn = b.joinColumn
```

You can see more info in the below links:

[Joining two unrelated tables in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758169/joining-two-unrelated-tables-in-hibernate)

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/04/theta-join-in-hql-join-with-unrelated-entities/

Comment: @angel_navarro so how do I make it a left outer join.

Comment: Sorry @AkhilKNambiar, I assumed It was an inner join. For outer join on unrelated entities I think you cannot use HQL, so you can use NativeSQL (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html) or indicate the relationship in your entities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `new` operator and a `DTO` class to set the values..

**Query**

```
 select new com.example.UCRMNP(uc.id, uc.name, mpn.name) from UCR uc, MpnMapping mpn;
```

**DTO class**

First can create a DTO class and specify all the column variables, like this

```
class UCRMNP{
 int id;
 String name;
 String name1;
 public UCRMNP( int id, String name, String name1){
 this.id=id;
 this.name=name;
 this.name1=name1;
}
}
```

> Now you can set the retrieved data to that specific DTO class, You dont want to
>   annotate it with anything, just specify the constructor and execute
>   the Query using new operator.